# Функция бесконечно повторяется python3 windows pynput pyautogui

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui, time
from pynput import keyboard

def jericho ():
    pyautogui.write('~jericho', interval=0.1)

def money():
    pyautogui.write('~add_money 2000', interval=0.1)

def on_press(space):
    money()
    #return False

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Программа должна слушать сочетание клавиш и при срабативаниы вызывать функцию (в даном случае money) .Проблема в том что создаетса цикл которий постояно печатает ~add_money 2000 а если сделать так

```
def on_press(space):
    money()
    return False
```

то программа не слушает сочетание клавиш дальше, а завершаеться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Надо так**

```
import pyautogui, time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def jericho ():
    pyautogui.write('~jericho', interval=0.1)

def money():
    pyautogui.write('~add_money 2000', interval=0.1)

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} press'.format(
        key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        money()

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

*И ещё что интересно вот вывод консоли)*

```
>>> ~aKey.esc press
dd_money 2000
Key.shift press
'`' press
Key.shift press
'a' press
'd' press
'd' press
Key.shift press
'-' press
Key.shift press
'm' press
'o' press
'n' press
'e' press
'y' press
Key.space press
'2' press
'0' press
'0' press
'0' press
```

Comment: Комментарии не нужны так что поосторожнее с этими двумя в паре)